# Vertical aligning an image in a left floated div with text on a right floated div

Tags: html, css, text, vertical-alignment, alignment

I'm having this problem where I have 2 divs on a content page (within a content wrapper) and I can't have the image aligned with the text next to it.

```
.text-block{position:relative; float:right; width:70%; height:auto}
```

then I have the image:

```
.img-block{position:relative; float:left; vertical-align:middle;}
```

Not sure if is possible to have an image aligned with text when they're in different divs though.

Comment: What do you mean by vertical align? The image should be in the middle of the text (top and bottom margin the same)? Or at the top? Or at the bottom?

Comment: Hi Entropy, I mean to have the image aligned with the text by the middle (not within the text) what the vertical-align:middle; does as default when it works.

Comment: I don't think you can do that just with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I've made text vertical align as middle next to a image div. Only CSS, no JavaScript used.

[Text Vertical Align Middle - Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Hariharan/9Mbfr/2/)

Hope this is the result you expect...

If you are looking for some thing more, pls make comment...

Comment: Hi there just passed by this post coz I have similar problem, Im trying to do same thing but I want to text to be vertically centred inside a div that is floated (using float:left), my text is centred as long as I don't float the div, once I do text appear on top